# How to reformat long date to short version in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column with dates in format

```
2017-12-05 12:16:20
```

I´d like to change the format to

```
05.12.2017
```

I tried it via right muse button > Format Cells > Date but even if I tried all short date versions my tables remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Format Cells, Custom, Type: dd.mm.yyyy

below, I pasted "2017-12-05 12:16:20" into cells A1 and A2, and reformatted A2 by entering "dd.mm.yyyy" in the "Type:" box in the "Format Cells" Custom dialog.

[image]